# What type should I use when declaring a template ref that is a single file component when using the Vue Composition API and TypeScript?

Tags: typescript, vue.js, templates, ref, vue-composition-api

I have a single file component that I made called `BusinessDetails`. I'm using this component in another component, and I've attached the `ref` attribute to it to access its properties and methods. If I don't give the `ref` a type, I get an error when accessing its methods that says `"Object is possibly null"`. I tried setting the type as `BusinessComponent`, `typeof BusinessComponent`, `Vue.extend(BusinessComponent)`, and so on, but they all throw different errors. I eventually settled on just setting the type to `any`, and living with the `eslint` warnings. While this goes around the problem, is there was an appropriate way to do this?

```html
<q-layout view="hHh LpR lfr">
    <q-header>
        <q-toolbar>
            <q-btn flat round @click="$router.go(-1)" icon="arrow_back" aria-label="Back"/>
            <q-toolbar-title>Create Account</q-toolbar-title>
        </q-toolbar>
    </q-header>

    <q-page-container>
        <q-page>
            <business-details ref="businessDetails" />
        </q-page>
    </q-page-container>
</q-layout>
```

```
export default Vue.extend({
    name: "CreateAccount",
    components: {
        BusinessDetails
    },
    setup () {
        const businessDetails: Ref<any> = ref(null);

        const isCurrentPageValid = (page: number): Promise<boolean> => {
            switch (page) {
                case AccountGroup.BUSINESS:
                    return businessDetails.value.isValid();
                default:
                    return Promise.resolve(true);
            }
        };

        return {
            businessDetails,
            isCurrentPageValid
        };
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `InstanceType<>`:

```js
const businessDetails = ref<InstanceType<typeof BusinessDetails> | null>(null);
```

This will give you typing for all the methods, etc. defined on the `BusinessDetails` component.

Then use it with

```js
businessDetails.value?.isValid();
```

and it should just work™.

The idea for this type came from the many responses in https://github.com/vuejs/vue/issues/8721

Answer (score 0):

You could use [lookup types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-2-1.html#keyof-and-lookup-types) to specify the component's type like this:

```js
type BusinessDetailsRef = Ref<
        typeof BusinessDetails['props']
      & typeof BusinessDetails['data']
      & typeof BusinessDetails['computed']
      & typeof BusinessDetails['methods']
      | null
    >

const businessDetails: BusinessDetailsRef = ref(null)
```

You can choose to include only the lookup types you're interested in to make it less verbose.

*Verified with:*

- TypeScript 3.9.7
- Vue 2.6.11
- Project generated from Vue CLI 4.4.6 (w/TypeScript option selected)
- macOS Catalina

Answer (score 0):

You can use the type `ComponentPublicInstance` from the `'vue'` package:

```
const businessDetails : Ref<ComponentPublicInstance | null> = ref(null);
```